# Django Assign M2M after Saving

Tags: django, m2m

I'm working on a project in Django and I have the following problem:

I have these two classes, Team and Project. When I create one project I want to automatically assign users from the team what was selected when I created the Project to the new project.
I override Project's save method and after the project was created assign users to the project(I did after saving because, before gave me an error). I tried of several ways but none of them works. 
Tried by:

```
self.user.add(*self.team.users.all())
self.save()
```

And this doesn't work.

Tried iterating:

```
for uTeam in self.team.users.all():
    self.users.add(uTeam)
```

and doesn't work either.

The only way that work for me is this, but only in the Django Shell:

```
P = Project.objects.get(pk=1)
T = Team.objects.get(pk=1)
P.user.add(*T.user.all())
P.save()
```

This is the solution that I have below but doesn't work in Django(gives an infinite loop)

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                            help_text=_('name of the team'))
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name="members_of_team",
                                help_text=_('users of the team'),
                                null=True
                                )
    and more....


class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                            help_text=_('name of project'),
                            )
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team,`enter code here`
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                             help_text=_('team of project'))
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                  on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                  related_name='creator_project',
                                  blank=True,
                                  null=False,
                                  help_text=_('project created by'))
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                help_text=_('customer'))
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                  related_name='users_team',
                                  blank=True,
                                  null=False,
                                  help_text=_('users of this project'))


   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

     if self.checkIntegrity():
       super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       if self.user.all().count() < self.team.user.all().count():
         T = Team.objects.get(pk=self.team.id)
         P = Project.objects.get(pk=self.id)
         P.user.add(*T.user.all())
         P.save()
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: just for clarification - adding users to project before saving project itself raise exception, because project hasn't primary key yet, so you can't assign user to (in that moment) non-existent project. Next - afaik there should not be any difference between adding users in iteration (your 2nd try) and adding them as a list (your current code in `save()`). Did you have some debug info, if it really looped thru that for-cycle?

Comment: What's happening is that P.save() call save of Project and checks integrity, call super(Project, Self), assign again T and P, and add users another time...
I noticed that is assigned but enters in an infinite loop that after some time gets an "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceed"

Comment: yep, that makes sense. But calling `P.save()` (the very last line isn't neccesary, right?

Comment: I tried without P.save(), but it doesn't save anything. It's strange that when I do it in django shell, I don't need to save that instance, but in django model I have to. I also tried by writing raw SQL and doesn't work either.

I have been checking the SQL Statements that make django and i see something strange. First I see this statement:

    INSERT INTO `time_counter_project_user` (`project_id`, `user_extended_id`) VALUES (109, 1), (109, 2)

This is called by a post_signal function that I created.

Comment: But later I get this statement:
    DELETE FROM `time_counter_project_user` WHERE    `time_counter_project_user`.`project_id` = 109

From:
python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in save_related(762)
  form.save_m2m()

So I think that if leave the form empty tries to delete all that was added before. Some solution to that?

Comment: What does `checkIntegrity()` do? You try to save it in custom view or in django-admin view?

Comment: checkIntegrity() is a method that checks the following:
   def checkIntegrity(self):
      t = Time.objects.filter(user=self.user.id, end_time__isnull=True).exclude(pk=self.id).count()
      p = Project.objects.filter(id=self.project.id, customer=self.customer.id, team__user=self.user.id).count()
      c = Customer.objects.filter(id=self.customer.id, team__user=self.user.id).count()
      if t == 0 and p != 0 and c != 0:
          return True
      else:
        return False

Is a sanity check to preventing inconsistent data.
I'm trying to save in django-admin view and in a RESTFul View

Comment: it's hard to read it over here, could you add it into original code above? And is there something special in your admin view or REST view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I read that m2m fields are filled after save() and post_save() and there is a signal that trigger when a m2m field is changed so I write the following:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Project.user.through)
def m2mChange(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    T = Team.objects.get(pk=instance.team.id)
    if kwargs['pk_set'] is None:
         instance.user.add(*T.user.all())
```

And now it works fine.
Thank you for all.